# Scala array to Java

Tags: java, scala

I have this invocation from scala class to Java

```
  private def initSpringActorContext: ConfigurableApplicationContext = {
    val resourceLocations = Array[String]("aopContext.xml", "akkaContext.xml")
    new GenericXmlApplicationContext(resourceLocations))
  }
```

And the java class expect

```
 public GenericXmlApplicationContext(String... resourceLocations) {
        this.load(resourceLocations);
        this.refresh();
    }
```

I´ve tried to cast this with `import collection.JavaConverters._`

But I cannot make it works with Arrays.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want an `Array`, but a varargs.

You should do `new GenericXmlApplicationContext(resourceLocations: _*)`

Comment: Wow that´s magic stuff, what the hell is the scala compiler doing internally there?! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Unlike in java, `String*` (scala varargs) is not the same as `Array[String]` in scala. Therefore, we just need to tell the compiler that we want to convert our `Array` to a varargs by typing it explicitly, which is done with the `_*` type.

Answer (score 2):

`GenericXmlApplicationContext` constructor accepts `varargs` as an argument.

You can use `: _*` syntax to solve the problem.

```
private def initSpringActorContext: ConfigurableApplicationContext = {
    val resourceLocations = Array[String]("aopContext.xml", "akkaContext.xml")
    new GenericXmlApplicationContext(resourceLocations: _*))
  }
```

`:` in this case is a hint to scala compiler about the type of the expression you have.

`_*` is a type annotation; it basically says accept any value of varargs (`_` for any, `*` for varargs)

Update: As mentioned in the comment, `: _*` is a fixed syntax; so above deconstruction is only for explanation purposes.

Comment: Actually, `_*` is a fixed syntax, you cannot replace `_` by `String` (see section 4.6.2 of [Scala spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)).

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet good point, I updated my answer to stress that. thnx